# AngularJS: Migrate Expression to Javascript (Coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have an expression I would like to migrate to javascript to keep an object's value available in `$scope`:

```
<dl class = "mortgage-information">
    <dt><abbr title = "Loan-to-value Ratio">LTV</abbr></dt>
    <dd>{{(total_financing ? total_financing : financing)/ property_value}}</dd>
</dl>
```

But migrating the same expression to javascript will always result in `financing` and not `total_financing` (Coffeescript):

```
$scope.ltv = (if $scope.total_financing then $scope.total_financing else $scope.financing) / $scope.property_value
```

I have been reading [the documentation on angular expressions to no avail](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).  Can anyone suggest a better method of migrating expressions to javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.ltv = ($scope.total_financing ? $scope.total_financing : $scope.financing) / $scope.property_value;
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: That isn't CoffeeScript.

Comment: It wasn't tagged coffeescript , it was tagged javascript when I answered it. Please read comments in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code is completely wrong. Firstly, javascript doesn't have an if-then construct like visual basic or some other languages, the syntax goes rather like this:

```
if(...) {
   doSomething
} else {
   do someThingElse
}
```

The other mistake you make is that you have to assign an expression to a variable and not a statement which the if-else construct is. You may as Nikhil suggested use a ternary operator or, if you aren't comfortable with ternary operators, a function like this:

```
$scope.ltv = function() {
   if($scope.total_financing) {
      return $scope.total_financing; 
   } 
   return $scope.financing;
}
```

and then use a function call in the html binding like `{{ltv()}}`

Comment: It's coffeescript, not javascript...  Editing question

Comment: Then you should have indicated this with your tags, I see only javascript and angularjs tabs and nowhere you mention coffeescript.

Comment: Fair enough.  I have update tags now (coffeescript is still javascript).

Comment: Coffeescript *is not* Javascript